# Replace whole page in browser

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to ask how to replace full address of page in browser.

**Example:**

```
www. myWebsite .com -> www. superWebsite .com
```

Is it possible to use **JavaScript** or **Ajax** or whatever?

It's for my education and own purpose on my laptop out of curiosity.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change **the value in address bar** without navigating to that website. You can navigate to another page using many of ways.

```
var domain= "www.superWebsite.com"
var url = "http://" + domain
// use one of following ways
location = url
window.location = url 
window.location.href = url    // will work in most browsers
window.location.assign(url)
window.location.replace(url)  // back button will not redirect to current page after navigating to `url`
```

Comment: That what I guess, I read that there is security of website and I cannot create aliase for any www page in adress bar. It might provide crimes, making PayPal fake page for example. Of course I would never do that, just I was curious studying IT. Thanks for replay.  I will test your code :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, then I think you want to navigate from one page to another,

For this you should use

```
var myWebLink = 'www.superWebsite.com'

window.location.href = myWebLink;
```

It will navigate to www. superWebsite .com

Comment: Thank for replay, I just want to replace text, not to go to another page. It might be like joke for flatemate that I creat www.myWebsite.com and convert it into www.faceBook.com in adress bar in internet explorer. Just swap text, creating aliase. I read that it is forbidden due to security sakes. Thanks for post  :)

Comment: thanks for help, not exactly what  I want. Please close this post